# How to Edit Web part in SharePoint 2013 Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I am not able to move the web part **Other Data** below the **Call Details**.
How can i do this?

I am trying to drag and drop the web part in SharePoint Designer 2013.

[image]

Comment: edit web part properties, change zone id and position?

Comment: I  try this but Zone id is disable so i am not able to change the zone id.

Comment: What type of page is it? Wiki page? Or Web part page? It looks like a Wiki page to me from the screenshot. You cannot change zones in Wiki pages. Can you not use a web part page instead?

Comment: How can i check type of my page b'ce i don't know the type of page i am new in SP..

Comment: Hi, activate the Publishing Feature under site settings > site feature if it's not already active. This will create a Pages library. If it's already there use it. Create a new page, select web part page.

Comment: I want to modify this page. I don't want to create new page is any way to i can do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44991/discussion-between-admin-and-ova).

Comment: Sorry I don't think you can edit web part zones on a wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

Select the **Edit Web-part** option for the `web-part` you need to change the position.

Then change the zone and zone index.

[image]

Comment: I try this but Zone drop down is disable. I am not able to change the zone value.

Comment: what type of page is this? sitepage or page?

Comment: How can i check page type?

Comment: go to the site content and there are two apps, one is sitepages and other is pages. see where is the page belong

Comment: This page type is sitepage.

Comment: So how can edit the web part for my sitepage.